# How to push Mercurial subrepositories to their own origin

Tags: mercurial, repository, tortoisehg, mercurial-subrepos, subrepos

I am using subrepositories to share code between multiple projects.
I keep the "master" version of these shared repositories in a central location.
That way I can easily push changes I made to them in one project and pull them in another.
That works, but ideally I want to just push the project repository and all subrepositories should be pushed to **their** origin. But Mercurial always pushes all subrepositories into the origin of the main repository.

This is my setup:

```
Project1 (default path = Project-Central-Location/Project1)
 - lib-A (default path = Library-Central-Location/lib-A)
 - lib-B (default path = Library-Central-Location/lib-B)

Project2 (default path = Project-Central-Location/Project2)
 - lib-A (default path = Library-Central-Location/lib-A)

Library-Central-Location
 - lib-A   <= push of Project1 should push lib-A to this location
 - lib-B

Project-Central-Location
 - Project1
   - lib-A <= push of Project1 pushes lib-A to this location instead
   - lib-B
 - Project 2
   - lib-A
```

Comment: A sub-repository *is* a repository in its own right, so you can `cd` into it and use it the way you would use any repository. That includes configuring paths in the repository if you'd like, and/or running `hg push` with a specific destination. You mention tortoisehg in tags, though, and this is all command-line stuff; I have no idea how to convince tortoisehg to be more capable.

Comment: I know I can push them individually, but this is cumbersome and error prone (I might forget). I will look into hooks and see if they can help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using hooks. First, the libraries inside the projects in the central location need to point to the corresponding central library repository:

```
Project-Central-Location
 - Project1
   - lib-A <= (default path = Library-Central-Location/lib-A)
   - lib-B <= (default path = Library-Central-Location/lib-B)
 - Project 2
   - lib-A <= (default path = Library-Central-Location/lib-A)
```

Then you need to add this to their `.hg/hgrc` files:

```
[hooks]
changegroup.hg-push = hg push
```

That way I will trigger a push to the central libraries anytime I push the projects.